# Is @Autowired annotation mandatory on constructor in Spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, dependency-injection, autowired

Is it mandatory to put `@Autowired` if I am using constructor DI?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Is @Autowired annotation mandatory for a constructor?

**No.**

As of [Spring 4.3](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-spring-beans-and-dependency-injection.html) if your class has only single constructor then there is no need to put `@Autowired`.

**Before Spring 4.3**:

```java
package com.example.service;
    
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
    
@Service
public class DatabaseAccountService implements AccountService {
    
    private final RiskAssessor riskAssessor;
    
    @Autowired
    public DatabaseAccountService(RiskAssessor riskAssessor) {
        this.riskAssessor = riskAssessor;
    }
    
    // ...
}
```

**After:**

```java
@Service
public class DatabaseAccountService implements AccountService {
    
    private final RiskAssessor riskAssessor;
    
    public DatabaseAccountService(RiskAssessor riskAssessor) {
        this.riskAssessor = riskAssessor;
    }
    
    // ...
}
```

**Extra: With Lombok, after Spring 4.3**

With [Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/) you can use `@RequiredArgsConstructor` to make the code even cleaner:

```java
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class DatabaseAccountService implements AccountService {
    private final RiskAssessor riskAssessor; 
}
```

Comment: Whats the benefit of Constructor vs Autowired? Is it preferred to do Constructor DI nowadays?

Comment: **Yes, Construct is preferred**. just google constructor vs field dependency injection.

Comment: Refer [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/300706/dependency-injection-field-injection-vs-constructor-injection)