# Lombok annotations has no effect

Tags: java, lombok

I have a spring boot app `2.0.5.RELEASE` with a **lombok** dependency for version **`1.18.2`** with `scope` set to `provided`.

An exmaple:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/users")
@AllArgsConstructor
public class UserController {

    private static final UserMapper mapper = Mappers.getMapper(UserMapper.class);

    private UserRepository repository;//It's null, nothing gets injected

    @GetMapping("/")
    public ResponseEntity<List<UserDTO>> getUsers() {

        final List<User> users = (List<User>) repository.findAll();

        return new ResponseEntity<>(users.stream()
                .map(mapper::toDto)
                .collect(Collectors.toList()), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

In that case I'm getting an error as `repository` field is `null`. When I remove lombok `@AllArgsConstructor` and put it directly:

```
public UserController(UserRepository repository) {
    this.repository = repository;
}
```

Then it works, a proper component is injected in the `repository` field. The same situation is for `UserDTO` class. It's definied:

```
@Getter @Setter
public class UserDTO {

    private int id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
}
```

**`Jackson`** is not able to find getters and throws an exception. Everything works fine if getters are created "normally" (without 3rd party libs).

What am I doing wrong? Why lombok is not generating things it should?

Comment: For Jackson to work, you also need to add `@NoArgsConstructor`

Comment: And that works without @Autowired on constructor?? Right it works since 4.3 https://stackoverflow.com/a/49893384/1527544

Comment: It's not working when you are building app with IDE or Maven/Gradle?
If IDE Lombok plugin should be installed

Comment: Why do you set scope to "provided"? IMO it shoud be "compile".

Comment: @PawełAdamski should not - you dont want to include lombok into resulting jar, you only want it on the classpath during compilation.

Comment: 1.) shouldn't be to compile https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29385921/maven-scope-for-lombok-compile-vs-provided
2.) I have plugin installed in my Intellij Idea IDE
3.) No need for `Autowired` annotation in this version of spring

Comment: @user3529850 that post says it should be *provided*. Probably you wanted to write "should not"

Comment: If setters are not visible through IDE, it seems that annotation processing is not enabled: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24006937/lombok-annotations-do-not-compile-under-intellij-idea
Or try to build app using maven or gradle command line

Comment: @user3529850 as for lombok constructors with DI check this https://www.baeldung.com/spring-injection-lombok.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I fixed it by ticking the "Enable annotation processing" checkbox in Settings->Compiler->Annotation Processors.

Comment: Worked. Thanks. I also had to do one moer thing: move project from `Maven default annotation processors` to `Default`

Answer (score 1):

Apart from other answers to enable annotation processing in Intellij IDE, we need to add a plugin to make the IDE understand Lombok Project.
Install the Lombok plugin: **Settings > Plugins > Lombok**.

Answer (score 0):

Settings->Build/Execution/Deployment - > Compiler->Annotation Processors -> Enable Annotation Processor   ckeck